# SWIFT APN being sent but not recieved

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

[image]

I can send a push notification from parse.com and it arrives at the devices just fine, but when sending from device to device it wont send. it then says "pushes sent - 0" like you can see in the picture.

Here is the code in the AppDelegate.swift file:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FBLoginView.self
    FBProfilePictureView.self
    initLocationManager();

    Parse.setApplicationId("key", clientKey: "key")
    let notificationTypes:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert
    let notificationSettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication!, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings!) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
}

func application(application: UIApplication!, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData!) {
    let currentInstallation:PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    currentInstallation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    currentInstallation.save()
}

func application(application: UIApplication!, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError!) {
    println(error.localizedDescription)
}

func application(application: UIApplication!, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo:NSDictionary!) {

    var notification:NSDictionary = userInfo.objectForKey("aps") as NSDictionary
    println(userInfo)

    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active) {
        var ln: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        ln.userInfo = userInfo
        ln.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        ln.alertBody = notification["alert"] as NSString
        ln.fireDate = NSDate()
        application.scheduleLocalNotification(ln)
        println("local")
    } else {
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    }

}
```

And in the send message method of the view controller:

```
var pushQuery: PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()
                        pushQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: SelectedUser.sharedInstance.getUsername())

                        var push:PFPush = PFPush()
                        push.setQuery(pushQuery)
                        var data: AnyObject = ["from" : GlobalVars.sharedInstance.getUserID(), "message" : txtMessage.text, "aps" : ["alert" : txtMessage.text, "badge" : "1"]] as NSDictionary
                        push.setData(data as NSDictionary)

                        push.sendPush(NSErrorPointer())
```

I have a feeling it has to do with the  `push.sendPush(NSErrorPointer())` line, I used to have `push.sendInBackground()` in my old app, but that is no longer an option?:

[image]

Please help, I am at the point of tearing my hair out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must say I don't know swift, but I think you should use `sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock()`. As far as I know the parse methods without background block will be executed on the main thread and this is not good way to do because it will also slow down all the visual stuff that are running on main thread.

I use parse with objective c but the only time I used methods withoud background thread, I use it in my own background block that I created.

And if it's not a problem, please tell me why sending push in background is not an option. Both method take exact same time to execute and the block just take care so the main thred keeps running. I can paste some objective c code to show you how I wrap the parse methods in my own. Hope it'll help you.

In header file i create my method to get all the contacts from parse:

```
- (void)allContacts:(void(^)(NSArray *contacts))completion;
```

And in implementation file:

```
- (void)allContacts:(void (^)(NSArray *))completion
{
    PFQuery *contactsQuery = [Contact query];
    [contactsQuery whereKey:@"createdBy" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [contactsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error && [objects count])
            if (completion) completion(objects);
        else
            if (completion) completion(nil);
    }];
}
```

So I just dont see any downsides with using blocks, at fist is seems a little too complicated, but at the end they'll help you a lot.

Comment: using the `sendInBackground()` method no longer appears in the dropdown menu, and it throws an error when I try to use it, and I can't figure out what parameters I need to use in swift to use `sendInBackgroundUsingBlock()`

Comment: Do you user pointers for user in this line? `pushQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: SelectedUser.sharedInstance.getUsername())`
I looked at the parse documentation site and there is currently no tutorial for APN in swift language. I think I can't help you buddy.

Comment: The SelectedUser.sharedInstance.getUsername()` is a custom Singleton Pattern Class of mine, not part of the API. All it does is returns the users username